# Why is my image an invalid argument on screen with "no host specified" when all my images are defined and included in assets?

Tags: flutter, dart, invalid-argument, flutter-assetimage

I'm working on a shopping app for a school project, and I'm trying to get my product images to show up on the various product detail screens. I used some sample images from flutter's Shrine sample app as I followed their tutorial - so all of my product images are in the assets folder.

I think I made some mistake with retrieving the images from assets because I received the following error in my product detail screen: Invalid Argument(s): No host specified in URI file...

[image]

and my images do not show up on any of the detail screens.

Here is the specific line of code in my product detail screen where I tried to retrieve the image:

[image]

I tried to backtrack by seeing where all these image variables are linked. Hovering over "image" in the code above gives me this showing that the image is a String in product.dart:

[image]

so I thought it would be useful to add the product.dart code here too:

```
  //constructor for product
   Product({
    required this.category,
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.price,
    required this.details,
    required this.description,
    required this.isFeatured,
    required this.image,
   });

  //declaring local instances
  //class constructor to pass data
  final Category category;
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final int price;
  final String details;
  final String description;
  final String image;
  bool isFeatured;

   void changeStateOfFavorite() {
    isFeatured = !isFeatured;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  String get assetName => '$id-0.jpg';
  String get assetPackage => 'shrine_images'; //i think this is the line where it is linked to assets but I'm not sure if this is the problem

  @override
  String toString() => "$name (id=$id)";

  findById(String productId) {}

   Map toJson() {
     return {
       'id':id,
       'name': name,
       'price': price,
       'image': image,
     };
   }

}
```

I'm very new to coding but I really need the help to get the project done, thank you to anyone who is willing to help! I appreciate it so much

Edit: endless listview scroll of image and product details
[image]

Edit 2: Listview builder code

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:MyShoppingApp/provider/CartProvider.dart';
import 'package:MyShoppingApp/db/cart_database.dart';
import 'package:MyShoppingApp/model/cart.dart';
import 'model/products_repository.dart';
import '../model/cart.dart';


class ProductDetailsPage extends StatelessWidget {

  static const routeName = '/user-products';
   ProductDetailsPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key); //const
  DBHelper dbHelper = DBHelper();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //get particular productId using the ModalRoute class
    final productId = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as String;
    print(productId);
    //use Provider package to find out ID by accessing method declared in Product()
    final loadedProduct = ProductsRepository().findById(productId);
   
    //List<bool> clicked = List.generate(10, (index) => false, growable: true);
      final cart = Provider.of<CartProvider>(context);
      void saveData(int index) {
        dbHelper
            .insert(
          CartItem(
            id: index,
            title: loadedProduct.name,
            price: loadedProduct.price.toDouble(),
            quantity: ValueNotifier(1),
            image: loadedProduct.image,
          ),
        )
            .then((value) {
          cart.addTotalPrice(loadedProduct.price.toDouble());
          cart.addCounter();
          print('Product Added to cart');
        }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
          print(error.toString());
        });
      }

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.orange[50],
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange[900],
        title: const Text("Product details "),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back_ios_outlined,
            color: Colors.black,
            semanticLabel: 'back to home',
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
      ),
        //body:
        body: ListView.builder(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 8.0),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: loadedProduct.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Card(
                //SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 300,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: Image.asset(
                        loadedProduct.image,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 10),
                    Text(
                      '\$${loadedProduct.price}',
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        fontSize: 20,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            primary: Colors.blueGrey.shade900),
                        onPressed: () {
                          saveData(Random().nextInt(1000));
                        },
                        child: const Text('Add to Cart')),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: Text(
                        loadedProduct.description,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        softWrap: true,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            })
    );
  }
  }
```

ProductRepository dart file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:MyShoppingApp/db/cart_database.dart';
//add product data
import 'package:MyShoppingApp/model/product.dart';

//to get all products at once or any particular product by its ID
//product class that uses mixins with ChangeNotifier
class ProductsRepository with ChangeNotifier {
  DBHelper dbHelper = DBHelper();

  static List<Product> loadProducts(Category category) {
    //linked list storing objects of type Product
    var allProducts = <Product>[
      Product(
        category: Category.accessories,
        id: "0",
        isFeatured: true,
        name: 'Vagabond sack',
        price: 120,
        details: "Nice fancy shirt",
        description: "Comfortable and minimalistic",
        image: "packages/shrine_images/0-0.jpg",
      ),
      Product(
        category: Category.accessories,
        id: "1",
        isFeatured: true,
        name: 'Stella sunglasses',
        price: 58,
        details: "",
        description: "",
        image: "packages/shrine_images/1-0.jpg",
      ),
      Product(
        category: Category.accessories,
        id: "2",
        isFeatured: false,
        name: 'Whitney belt',
        price: 35,
        details: "",
        description: "",
        image: "packages/shrine_images/2-0.jpg",
      ),
      Product(
        category: Category.accessories,
        id: "3",
        isFeatured: true,
        name: 'Garden strand',
        price: 98,
        details: "",
        description: "",
        image: "packages/shrine_images/3-0.jpg",
      ),
      Product(
        category: Category.accessories,
        id: "4",
        isFeatured: false,
        name: 'Strut earrings',
        price: 34,
        details: "",
        description: "",
        image: "packages/shrine_images/4-0.jpg",
      ),//removed other products to save space
    ];

    if (category == Category.all) {
      return allProducts;
    } else {
      return allProducts.where((Product p) {
        return p.category == category;
      }).toList();
    }
  }

  //to get particular products by ID
  Product findById(String id) {
    var x = loadProducts(Category.all).firstWhere((prod) => prod.id == id);
    print("findById successful");
    print(x);
    return x;
  }
  
  void addProduct() {
    // _items.add(value);
    notifyListeners();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Image.network` is for online image what you give it a url and it download the image. If you store all your image in assets folder inside app you should use `Image.asset`, like this:

```
Image.asset(loadedProduct.image)
```

**Edit** for endless list issue try this:

define variable out of build method:

```
List loadedProduct = [];
```

then in init state do this:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      final productId = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as String;
      print(productId);
      //use Provider package to find out ID by accessing method declared in Product()
      setState(() {
         loadedProduct = ProductsRepository().findById(productId);
      });
    });
  }
```

and remove all these you added from build method.

Comment: Thank you so much! It fixed the problem. But it gives me and endless listview scroll with the image and product details repeated. Any idea how I could go about fixing this? I've attached the image in the post. Thanks again, I really appreciate it!

Comment: glad to here that, for new issue, please add add your full listview code

Comment: Added the listview code above, thank you!

Comment: I mean full class code that list view is in it.

Comment: Sorry, I have just added the whole dart file for the product detail screen

Comment: could also include ProductsRepository class?

Comment: Sure, I have just added that, Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, by that did you mean I should replace everything from `Widget build(BuildContext context)` to `void initState()`?

Comment: not every thing, just those I add in initState.

Comment: I'm quite unsure how to go about editing my code without causing even more errors for this page. I don't want to trouble you anymore though, because you have helped me so much thus far! I have reposted the problem as I didn't want to bombard you with so many questions. Thank you so much for all your help!